# How to send messages from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ?

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq

I have PostgreSQL server installed in Windows.
I'd like to send messages to RabbitMQ in functions and triggers.
How can I do this? What additional tolls do I need?

Answer (score 3):

You should use **logical replication** and write code or script for the append database change in RabbitMQ queue, also you can use [pg-bifrost](https://github.com/Nextdoor/pg-bifrost) from github. This code use [Logical Decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html) (this feature use in postgres 9.6 and above) and RabbitMQ.